# security for a simple php search form

Tags: forms, security, search

I have a table that lists movies and I have incorporated a simple search function.
I have one text field in a form where a title or keyword can be entered and then the form is submitted.

php/mysql code that does the work is:

```
$find = $_POST['find'];
$find = mysql_real_escape_string($find);
$find = htmlspecialchars($find);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_buyerguide WHERE rel_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND title LIKE '%".$find."%' ORDER BY title";
```

where 'find' is the name of the text input in the search form.

This works well enough for the search functionality for the required purpose.

My question to all is:

Is the mysql_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars enough to make my search form secure?

I have read all of the questions that I can find on stackoverflow about this, but I would really like someone in the know to just say to me "yes, that is all you need", or "no, you also need to take into account ...".

Thanks in Advance.
Cheers Al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is enough to make it secure....you could always throw strip_tags() in there as well....

Although I would just do it in one line...instead of using three

```
   $find = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['find']));
```

But to really make it secure and up to date, you should stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated, and will be removed in any future relases of PHP....

You should instead switch to either mysqli_* or PDO, and implement prepared statements which handles security for you.

Example...in PDO

```
   $db = new PDO('mysql:server=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');

   $find = $_POST['find'];

   $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_buyerguide WHERE rel_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND title LIKE :like ORDER BY title');
   $query->bindValue(':like', '%' . $find . '%');
   $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks KyleK, I must say, I have never heard of either, but I am self taught, so my knowledge is patchy and I have only been at it for a couple of years now. I will look into PDO. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Remember the adage: *Filter In, Escape Out*.

You're not outputting the term there, so why are you escaping it for HTML purposes with `htmlspecialchars()`?

Instead, ONLY escape it for the database (you should be using prepared statements, but that's another point). So you should **not** be using htmlspecialchars there.

Instead, when you go to output the variable onto the HTML page, that's when you should escape it for HTML (again, using `htmlspecialchars`).

Right now, you're mixing database and html escaping, which is going to lead to neither being effective...

Comment: +1. Due to the inappropriate escaping, it's not possible to search for  terms that have an ampersand in (or the other HTML-special characters). Escaping is not a problem you can solve at the input stage.

Comment: +1 for the adage. Simple way of remembering important information. I know this is an old question, but if you could clarify what do you mean by filtering? I already got the "escape" concept clear.